# Incorrect Ellipsis Layout/Rendering on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, textview, ellipsis

I'm having a peculiar issue with ellipses, just on an HTC One XL running Android 4.2.2.  On most devices the layout is correct, but on this device whenever text is ellipsized, it left-aligns itself and doesn't render completely.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

[image]

Each row is made of two TextViews in a LinearLayout oriented horizontally.  Below is the style for the "score"--the problematic textview.

```
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/content_section_scores_item_score_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
```

Comment: I'm getting something simular to this on a huawei phone running 4.0.1.  Hope you find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Painfully, the fix was quite simple.

A change from

```
<item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
```

fixed it.